# How to copy a php file to a csv file and download it?

Tags: php, csv, download, copy

I want to copy an entire php file into a csv file and download it, but the `demo.csv` file that I get is empty. Why am I getting an empty file?

The data in the php file is stored per line.

```
<?php
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="demo.csv"');

// do not cache the file
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

$handle = fopen("caldataprog.php", "r"); //fileurl
$lines = [];
if (($handle = fopen("caldataprog.php", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $lines[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen('demo.csv', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you finally copy a file to other and don't flush this last.

```
<?php

$source = 'caldataprog.php'; // Presuming it contains raw CSV
$destination = 'demo.csv';

copy($source, $destination);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="demo.csv"');
readfile($destination); // Send file to user
```

If caldataprog.php generates CSV and you want to copy the result, you can do :

```
$source = 'http://yourwebsite.net/caldataprog.php';
$destination = 'demo.csv';
copy($source, $destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the output data to a file named `demo.csv` on your server, and you are downloading a file named `demo.csv` in your browser, but *they are not the same file*.

If you want to download the file in your browser, you need to have PHP output the file's contents.

You could do this using [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile), or by just using `echo` while you are reading the original input file (and never save the local `demo.csv` on the server's disk).